# How do I use AutofacWebTypesModule to Resolve HttpServerUtilityBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

I have the following registrations

```
    builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
    builder.Register<MyType>(ctx =>
    {
        var server = ctx.Resolve<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        ...
    });
```

When I try to resolve MyType via a constructor on an Controller, I get the following exception. What am I doing wrong?

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
>   was unhandled by user code
>   Message=No scope matching the
>   expression
>   'value(Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder`3+<>c__DisplayClass0[System.Web.HttpServerUtilityBase,Autofac.Builder.SimpleActivatorData,Autofac.Builder.SingleRegistrationStyle]).lifetimeScopeTag.Equals(scope.Tag)'
>   is visible from the scope in which the
>   instance was requested.

Answer (score 1):

Yikes - that error message has gone all wrong :)

The problem is most likely that you're trying to resolve `MyType` directly from the container (as opposed to the `DependencyResolver` or else you're taking a dependency on it from a singleton. The `HttpServerUtilityBase` component can only be used in the context of a web request.

Trying to resolve it from `Applicaiton_Start` will also fail in IIS7 integrated pipeline mode.

HTH!
Nick